# Kernel of a linear transformation of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: P_2 \rightarrow P_3$ be defined by $T(p(x)) = xp(x)$

Find the kernel of T:

As far as I know,

$ker(T) = \{ p(x) \in P_2 : xp(x) = 0\}$

Can I expand it to:

$ker(T) = \{ a + bx + cx^2 \in P_2 : x(a + bx +cx^2) = 0\}$

If this was the case, then what we need to do is look for the zero polynomial, which implies that the kernel is the set of all polynomials in $P_3$ with $a=b=c=0$, but where does that leave us? This does not make sense to me.

Comment: It makes sense, it just means the kernel contains only the null polynomial. Notice also that the kernel is a subspace of $P_2$, not $P_3$. Precisely, it's $T^{-1}(\{0\})$.

Comment: You should clarify what $P_2$, $P_3$ are. Since this is not standard notation, it might not be obvious to everyone

Comment: Express this using the transformation matrix with respect to the standard basis and look for the nullity of it, it becomes quite obivious

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Oh okay, so since the dimension of the nullity is zero, this implies that the dimension of the rank is 3 since the dimension of $P_3$ in this case is $3$?

Comment: Please try to explain, what exactly doesn't make sense to you. You haven't really posed a question, that you didn't answer yourself already. Definitions of kernels etc unclear?

Comment: No, the [rank theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) states that $\dim \mathrm{im}\; T + \dim \ker T=\dim P_2$. Here $T$ has rank $2$.

Comment: @cQQkie I was confused with the idea of a null polynomial, but it is now clear. I will edit my post to clarify $P_2$ and $P_3$

Comment: Note: the dimension of $P_2$ is $3$ and the dimension of $P_3$ is $4$.